# How to calculate inter pupil and inter ocular distance for facial landmarks in python

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have been looking for a way to calculate the inter-pupil and interocular distance in python to evaluate the facial landmarks localization for 68 landmarks. The 68 landmarks do not have points on pupils. I was not able to understand the basic idea. I would really appreciate it if anyone could provide me some ideas or methods to calculate these metrics. Thank you in advance.

Edit: distance calculation within an image not for the 3D model.

Comment: This question is too vague. For example, are you looking for distance within an image or in 3D? Do you have a model for the face - specifically, for the location of the landmarks with respect to the eyes?

Comment: @FrancescoCallari I am looking within an image. Yes, the location of the landmarks with respect to the eyes.